# Fix the Proguard return with error code 1 com.google.android.gms.internal and tagmanager but then apk run error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Problem occur after upgrade to api23. Program compile and run ok just when exported with proguard error like below:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console\par [2015-10-31 11:22:10 -  Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase\par [2015-10-31 11:22:10 -] Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair\par
.......
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient\par
.......
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzby: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient\par
.......
```

Googled and read the similar problem from stackoverflow and try to add:

```
-dontwarn com.google.gms.** -dontwarn org.apache.**
```

The creation of apk then ok proguard no error, but when the apk tested run on phone it's error. While if compiled directly via usb cable it's run fine. And before upgrade api23 proguard and apk export run no problem.

Comment: Oh more information I'm using eclipse

Comment: Well it looks like google problem as I read in here:https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=3001